# Android MapView, how to change location/Marker on button press

Tags: java, android

In my application I allow the user to enter a Lat/Lon and would like my mapview in my searchfragment to update the location when the user presses enter in the searchview. I cant seem to find any information on how to update to that position. OnMapReady is called once the fragment is created but I cant figure out how to update the position when searchview is clicked. I have read through the mapview developer documentation and cant seem to find any info on how to update the marker/location. Also would it be better for me to use mapfragment and nest a mapfragment in my searchfragment to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method for get submit event when you hit search option from searchview.
you also can have a deep understanding of this from [this Webpage](https://dev.to/foso/how-to-use-a-searchview-with-an-empty-query-text-submit-4afh)

```
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
  @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
       //Perform task that you want 
    return false;
  }
  @Override public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Now  you can use below code to add Marker on MAP where Latlng is object of Latlng.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Latlng).title("Marker's Title")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getColorCompletedpin())));
```

Function getColorCompletepin()

```
 final public Bitmap getColorCompletedpin()    {
        Bitmap ob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_pin);
        Bitmap obm = Bitmap.createBitmap(ob.getWidth(), ob.getHeight(), ob.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(obm);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#c4ff15"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ob, 0f, 0f, paint);
        return obm;
    }
```